# Flask framework on Openshift unable to load module

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, paas, openshift

So I have created a flask application in OS from the OS quickstart on github. The app works great on my local system. when i push the app to OS it builds but I get an error 500 in the browser.

Any ideas or assistance would be appreciated.

Here is the source code from the application file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python import os

virtenv = os.environ['APPDIR'] + '/virtenv/'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(virtenv, 'lib/python2.6/site-packages')
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass

from run import app as application
```

Here is the source from the run.py file

```
from app import app 
app.run(debug = True)
```

Here are the errors from the logs (Stripped the HASH ID for my site):

```
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:08 2012] [error] * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:08 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] mod_wsgi (pid=28484): Target WSGI script '/var/lib/stickshift/HASH-ID-HERE/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/application' cannot be loaded as Python module. 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:08 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] mod_wsgi (pid=28484): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/lib/stickshift/HASH-ID-HERE/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/application'. 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:08 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] Traceback (most recent call last): 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:08 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] File "/var/lib/stickshift/HASH-ID-HERE/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/application", line 13, in <module> 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:08 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] from run import app as application 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:08 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] File "/var/lib/stickshift/HASH-ID-HERE/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/run.py", line 2, in <module> 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:08 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] app.run(debug = True) 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:08 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] File "/var/lib/stickshift/HASH-ID-HERE/ws/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.6.egg/flask/app.py", line 739, in run 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:08 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] run_simple(host, port, self, **options) 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:08 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] File "/var/lib/stickshift/HASH-ID-HERE/ws/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.8.3-py2.6.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 613, in run_simple 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:08 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] test_socket.bind((hostname, port)) 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:08 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] File "<string>", line 1, in bind 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:08 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] error: [Errno 13] Permission denied 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:09 2012] [error] * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:09 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] mod_wsgi (pid=31302): Target WSGI script '/var/lib/stickshift/HASH-ID-HERE/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/application' cannot be loaded as Python module. 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:09 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] mod_wsgi (pid=31302): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/lib/stickshift/HASH-ID-HERE/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/application'. 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:09 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] Traceback (most recent call last): 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:09 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] File "/var/lib/stickshift/HASH-ID-HERE/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/application", line 13, in <module> 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:09 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] from run import app as application 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:09 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] File "/var/lib/stickshift/HASH-ID-HERE/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/run.py", line 2, in <module> 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:09 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] app.run(debug = True) 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:09 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] File "/var/lib/stickshift/HASH-ID-HERE/ws/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.6.egg/flask/app.py", line 739, in run
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:09 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] run_simple(host, port, self, **options) 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:09 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] File "/var/lib/stickshift/HASH-ID-HERE/ws/virtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.8.3-py2.6.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 613, in run_simple 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:09 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] test_socket.bind((hostname, port)) 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:09 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] File "<string>", line 1, in bind 
[Sun Aug 05 15:46:09 2012] [error] [client 127.3.153.129] error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have finally figured out what was wrong with my code. I was missing a line in my run.py file so the incorrect file looked like this:

Incorrect file:

```
from app import app
app.run()
```

This is the corrected working file:

```
from app import app
if __name__ == "__main__": #Need this line for Openshift
    app.run()
```

The if statement is apparently needed when deployed to production servers like Apache

Comment: Correct - the issue is that when using `mod_wsgi` or other similar tools the application will be started and managed by mod_wsgi.  `Flask.run` starts a development server.  If you don't stop the dev server from starting when loaded by mod_wsgi then Flask's server attempts to bind to a port - which the user it is running as does not have permissions to do (hence the error).

Answer (score 2):

You should not be trying to run the Flask built in development server when hosting under mod_wsgi. Go back and check the mod_wsgi documentation in Flask as to what you are meant to be doing.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the following description from flask website at:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/#working-with-virtual-environments

> **Problem**: application gives permission errors
>       Probably caused by your application running as the wrong user. Make sure the folders the application needs access to have the proper
>   privileges set and the application runs as the correct user (user and
>   group parameter to the WSGIDaemonProcess directive)